# cURL Login on Website

Tags: php, curl, authentication

here´s my problem:

I´m trying to get the content of a website that first needs a login. I wanted to solve this via cURL.
First I´m connecting to the Login-Page, than to a page that requires the login.
I get some Cookies in my cookie file back, but when I try to see the content of the page that requires a login before, I only get redirected to (get the content of) the login page.
Seems that parsing my login cookie or whatever fails, so the website don´t remeber that I logged in.

Heres is my php-Code so far:

```
<?php
$loginUrl = 'https://www.****./login.html';



$loginFields = array('j_username'=>'***', 'j_password'=>'**'); //login form field names and values
$remotePageUrl = 'https://www.***/myPage/index.html'; //url of the page I want the content  

$login = getUrl($loginUrl, 'post', $loginFields); //login to the site

echo $remotePage = getUrl($remotePageUrl); //get the remote page

function getUrl($url, $method='', $vars='') {
    $ch = curl_init();

if ($method == 'post') {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
}
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'C:\\xampp\htdocs\***\cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'C:\\xampp\htdocs\****\cookies.txt');

 $buffer = curl_exec($ch);

 if (curl_error($ch)) echo curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);

return $buffer;
}

?>
```

Any ideas? Searched now for hours in the web, and didn´t find a solution yet.
Thanks!

Comment: What about any hidden input fields? Make sure those are passed in addition to the username and password

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I´ve inspected the website and didn´t find any other input fields. Normal login on the page with my only credentials name and password works.

Comment: Have you validated that there are actually values being written to the cookiejar?  And that the permissions are right...?

Comment: After the cURL request I´ve two cookies in my cookies text file. Don´t really know, whether there is a difference between this and the cookiejar? In one of the cookies there is a session id and so on. What do you mean by permission? Do I have to set special permissions or do you mean its not allowed to login for me on an external website? Anyway thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any solution. Nevertheless I did all the work manually and don´t need the programm anymore, anyway thanks for the comments :)